# How to automate the console application exe using cake build

Tags: .net, configuration, automation, cakebuild

I have created console application and we want to automate the console application using cake build. I have tried with following techniques.

Convert the console application to nugget package and host in nexus server. After that include package in cake build. While run the cake build the packages are downloaded but the console application is not run.

Try with cake attribute option and run the cake build but the console application not running.

https://github.com/SharpeRAD/Cake.SqlTools/blob/master/src/Cake.SqlTools/Aliases/SqlQueryAliases.cs

Please suggest how to automate the console application in cake build.

Sample Code Snippet

In C# code added the cake method alias attribute and convert tool to nugget package and upload in nexus server.

```
[CakeMethodAlias]
public static void SampleTool()
{
   SampleMethods();
}
```

In cake build script include the  nugget package and call the cake method alias method. Run the cake build the nugget package are downloaded but the sampleTool method not recognized error thrown.

```
#tool nuget:?package=SampleTool&version=1.0.0

Task("ToolAutomation")
.Does(() =>
{
SampleTool();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A script alias method is simply an extension method for [`ICakeContext`](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Core/ICakeContext/).

So you need to change `SampleTool()` to an extension method like:

```
[CakeMethodAlias]
public static void SampleTool(this ICakeContext context)
{
   SampleMethods();
}
```

Also see [docs about Script Aliases](https://cakebuild.net/docs/fundamentals/aliases)